# add powerpoint slide from excel without references

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

Good morning,

I have an excel file from which  create  slides in powerpoint . To do this I used the vba and everything worked using references to PowerPoint Objects.

However, this file should be used on multiple machines with different versions of Office so I can not use references .
I have error at the line "Set pptLayout = Presentazione.Slides ( 1 ) .CustomLayout ": RunTime error 438

How do I fix ?

Is there a method to add a blank slide A4 dimensions instead using ppCustomLayout ???

```
Option Explicit
'Public PPSlide As Slide
'Public Plate As Variant
Public PlatesOnSheet, Sheet As Single
Public TextOfPlate As String
Public Copies, HowMuch, RowNumber, LastRow As Integer
'Public PPPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
'Public pptLayout As CustomLayout
Public PlateHeight As Single
Public PPPresentation, PPSlide, Plate, pptLayout, PowerPointApp As Object

Public Sub Plates()
Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
PowerPointApp.Visible = True

Set PPPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open("P:\Per Officina\DA E PER MASSIMO G\Plates MT\NUOVA\Plates mt.pptm", msoTrue)
Set pptLayout = PPPresentation.Slides(1).CustomLayout
Sheet = 1
PlatesOnSheet = 0
PlateHeight = 35
LastRow = 27
While Cells(LastRow, 2) <> "totale"
    LastRow = LastRow + 1
Wend
LastRow = LastRow - 2
For RowNumber = 2 To LastRow
    TextOfPlate = Cells(RowNumber, 1)
    If Cells(RowNumber, 2) = "" Then
        Copies = 0
    Else
        Copies = Cells(RowNumber, 2)
    End If
    If Copies = 0 Then GoTo SaltaTextOfPlate:
    For HowMuch = 1 To Copies
        If PlatesOnSheet < 5 Then
            Call CreatePlate
        Else
            PlatesOnSheet = 0
            PPPresentation.Slides.AddSlide Index:=Sheet + 1, pcustomlayout:=pptLayout
            Sheet = Sheet + 1
            PlateHeight = 35
            Call CreatePlate
        End If
    Next
SaltaTextOfPlate:
Next
If PlatesOnSheet < 5 Then
    Copies = 5 - PlatesOnSheet
    TextOfPlate = Application.InputBox(Copies & " blank plates remain: complete with?")
    For HowMuch = 1 To Copies
        Call CreatePlate
    Next
End If
End Sub

Public Sub CreatePlate()
Set PPSlide = PPPresentation.Slides(Sheet)
Set Plate = PPSlide.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, Left:=61, Top:=PlateHeight, Width:=428.0315, Height:=144.5669)
With Plate.TextFrame.TextRange
    .Text = TextOfPlate
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Name = "Arial Narrow"
    .Font.Size = 36
    .Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 2
End With
Plate.Line.Visible = True
Plate.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Plate.TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
PlatesOnSheet = PlatesOnSheet + 1
PlateHeight = PlateHeight + 144.5669
End Sub
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are embedding Excel graphs into Powerpoint, right? If so, why don't you just COPY-PASTE LINKED the graphs? This way, you don't need VBA at all.

Comment: By the way, as a courtesy to those reviewing your code and are not fluent in Italian, you may consider writing your code in using ENGLISH variable names.

Comment: No I don't have to copy graphs from excel to powerpoint. I change the variables name.

Comment: You can have several parts of the same Excel being deployed in your powerpoint. for instance, you could copy-paste linked a cell into which the powerpoint user would enter a value. This would cause the excel to be updated and the result within powerpoint be updated as well. This is just an idea though.

Comment: Use Late Binding. See this [link](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/EarlyLateBinding.html) which is what you're trying to do but declare your variables correctly. See this [link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/declaringvariables.aspx) for proper declaration of variable.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you declare variables in VBA, each one has to be explicitly declared as a type. The separation via commas with a single type declaration at the end of the line does not work as you are expecting. For example, this line:

Public Copies, HowMuch, RowNumber, LastRow As Integer

declares the first three variables as Variant (since no type is specified) and only the last one an Integer. If they are all to be of type Integer, you must do this:

Public Copies As Integer, HowMuch As Integer, RowNumber As Integer, LastRow As Integer

To use Late Binding:

1. Declare all PowerPoint objects as type Object
2. Remove the PowerPoitn library reference from your project

Note that by doing this, you loose the IntelliSense feature of VBA so do it once all debugging is complete.

You can of course use conditional compiler constants to write code that supports both Early and Late Binding e.g.

```
' Change to False and remove PowerPoint reference for Late Binding
#Const EarlyBinding = True

#If EarlyBinding Then
  Public PPPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
  Public PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
  ' etc.
#Else
  Public PPPresentation As Object
  Public PPSlide As Object
  ' etc.
#End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this code:

```
Option Explicit
Public PlatesOnSheet, Sheet As Single
Public TextOfPlate As String
Public Copies, HowMuch, RowNumber, LastRow As Integer
Public pptLayout
Public PlateHeight As Single
Public PPPresentation, PPSlide, Plate, PowerPointApp As Object

Public Sub Plates()
Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
PowerPointApp.Visible = True

Set PPPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open("P:\Per Officina\DA E PER MASSIMO G\TARGHE MT\NUOVA\targhe mt.pptm", msoTrue)
Sheet = 1
PlatesOnSheet = 0
PlateHeight = 35
LastRow = 27
While Cells(LastRow, 2) <> "TOTALE"
    LastRow = LastRow + 1
Wend
LastRow = LastRow - 2
For RowNumber = 2 To LastRow
    TextOfPlate = Cells(RowNumber, 1)
    If Cells(RowNumber, 2) = "" Then
        Copies = 0
    Else
        Copies = Cells(RowNumber, 2)
    End If
    If Copies = 0 Then GoTo SaltaTextOfPlate:
    For HowMuch = 1 To Copies
        If PlatesOnSheet < 5 Then
        Set PPSlide = PPPresentation.Slides(Sheet)
            Call CreatePlate
        Else
            PlatesOnSheet = 0
            Set PPSlide = PPPresentation.Slides.Add(Sheet + 1, 12)
            Sheet = Sheet + 1
            PlateHeight = 35
            Call CreatePlate
        End If
    Next
SaltaTextOfPlate:
Next
If PlatesOnSheet < 5 Then
    Copies = 5 - PlatesOnSheet
    TextOfPlate = Application.InputBox(Copies & " blank plates remain: complete with?")
    For HowMuch = 1 To Copies
        Call CreatePlate
    Next
End If
End Sub

Public Sub CreatePlate()

Set Plate = PPSlide.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, Left:=61, Top:=PlateHeight, Width:=428.0315, Height:=144.5669)
With Plate.TextFrame.TextRange
    .Text = TextOfPlate
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Name = "Arial Narrow"
    .Font.Size = 36
    .Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 2
End With
Plate.Line.Visible = True
Plate.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
If Application.Version <> "11.0" Then Plate.TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = 3
PlatesOnSheet = PlatesOnSheet + 1
PlateHeight = PlateHeight + 144.5669
End Sub
```